How do I associate a saved Data Explorer query with a single site?
I have some saved-queries in data.stackexchange that shows me my top-voted comments using WHERE c.UserId = @myUserId ...so far, so egotistical.
...but because my UserId is different on each site (e.g. on SO it's 159145, on DBA it's 10044, on SuperUser it's 41739, etc) I created one saved query for each site, where each saved query has a different DECLARE @myUserId int = /* 159145 or 10044 or 41739 etc */;.
...and just now I noticed that the Data Explorer doesn't actually associate each saved query with a single specific StackExchange website/database, instead the actual website/database used in the query will be the last website I selected in the Compose Query widget - or from whatever is in the address bar: https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/{myDbaSEQuery} vs https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/{myDbaSEQuery}. So this means that I can't simply middle-click my saved queries and have them work, instead they'll all return zero results (due to the incorrect @myUserId value) except for the query that coincidentally was written for the currently selected site, if any.
So is there a way to tell data.stackexchange that I want each query to run only in a single specific website/database?
...or, alternatively, is there a way for a query to detect which database it's running in and so could switch-out my @myUserId accordingly, something like the @currentSite in this hypothetical query below:
DECLARE @myUserId int = ( CASE @currentSite WHEN 'stackoverflow' THEN 159145 WHEN 'superuser' THEN 41739 WHEN 'dba' THEN 10044 END );

IF( @myUserId IS NULL ) THROW 51000, 'Unknown StackExchange Data Explorer site selected.', 1;

SELECT TOP 100 c.* FROM dbo.Comments WHERE c.UserId = @myUserId ORDER BY c.Score DESC;


More of a workaround, but you can make that variable actually vary if you turn it into a query parameter: DECLARE @myUserId int = ##UserId:int## then you can have a bookmark for your query with ?UserId=<whatever> appended at the end. Maybe even one bookmark per site.


...or, alternatively, is there a way for a query to detect which database it's running in and so could switch-out my @myUserId accordingly, something like the @currentSite in this hypothetical query below:


You can JOIN your query with the Users table and filter on AccountId -   yours is 53229, which can be seen in you network profile: https://stackexchange.com/users/53229/dai
I had this problem too, and decided to write a userscript that automatically populates the  ##UserId## parameter, which used to be feature of SEDE itself.


So is there a way to tell data.stackexchange that I want each query to run only in a single specific website/database?

That is possible too, by using the database name to fully qualify the table. Here is an example - SEDE says the query runs on Stack Overflow, but it returns your Meta.SE user information.

